# Iterate through QLineSeries items and their points

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I need to sort QLineSeries and points inside them by their y axis. I'm newbie to c++ and qt so I tried

```
QLineSeries* series = lineSeriesMap.value(key);
qSort(series->points().begin()->y(),series->points().end()->y());
```

But this gives me `illegal indirection` error at `qalgorithms.h`

I know this may be something easy but I need to do this due to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you should do is get a copy of the points, order the points and replace the points in the initial series

```
QVector<QPointF> points = series->pointsVector();
std::sort(points.begin(), points.end(), [](const QPointF & p1, const QPointF & p2) {
    return p1.y() > p2.y();
});
series->replace(points);
```

Comment: Can I ask you something more? How do I copy QLineSeries* series into a new object?

Answer (score 0):

C++20

```
auto points { series->pointsVector() }; // move ctr
std::ranges::sort(points, {}, &QPointF::y); // #include <ranges>
series->replace(points);
```